# Customize an Intrusion Detection System for serial communication

Tags: ids

Most of the Intrusion detection Systems I know of is for IP Communication. But, lets assume that I have serial communication, i.e. CAN or RS485. On this serial Communication there are customized protocols communicating, such that the analysis of traffic can be pretty static.

Does anyone know of an IDS which is possible to customize for this purpose?

It does not have to be a finished Product, just a reference to a paper or document would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research we have found several interesting solutions, here are three papers that I found most relevant:

*Anagram: A Content Anomaly Detector Resistant to Mimicry Attack* by Wang et al. They construct a content anomaly detector called Anagram. Anagrams works by analyzing byte sequences using distinct n-grams to learn itself signatures of valid packets. According to the authors it has high accuracy and low false positive rates. Also, it can operate at high-speed making it useful for network intrusion detection. Since it is anomaly-based it has a greater chance of detecting zero-day exploits. And, because it is self-learning, it does not require a lot of attention from the supervisor.

Another interesting paper is *Anomalous payload-based network intrusion detection* by Wang et al. It is also fully automatic and can be runned unsupervised. As with other Anomaly-based IDS they have a training phase in which the system learn the frequency and standard deviation of the payload. This solution has also a high detection rate, near 100%, and a very low false positive rate.

The paper found in this answer https://security.stackexchange.com/a/24553/53067 has also been helpful.

None of the solutions above address serial communication. However, operating on byte level communication, we believe a similar solution can be applied on, for example: RS485 or CAN.